# 98 Dodge Ram van b2500, 5.2L gas, 223k miles, runs great overall......stumbles when cold.

Tags: fuel-system, dodge, acceleration, ram, van

OK, the title spells it out, I need some direction from you guys, thanks in advance.

Have not really had time to dig-around, so if anyone can offer me a direction on where to look, much appreciated!!! It has only stalled-out once when cold, but you can feel it stumbling, hit the gas when cold and it comes close to dying, HELP!

Comment: What's been done as far as tune up? Does it need new spark plugs, O2 sensors, air filter, clean the MAF and throttle body? While this may not be the issue, if it's in need of it, it won't hurt anything, will eliminate it as a suspect, and darn sure may help.

Comment: Thanks, all the ignition parts looks quite old, ditto for 02-sensors. I bet you are right, doing some of the basics should help.